# How do you write data to an XML file in Actionscript 3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have seen a bunch of tutorials on how to read data from an external XML file in actionscript 3, but I want to know if it is possible to edit and add to the XML file from actionscript and how to do it. Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible, but you only have access to the filesystem via AIR projects as far as I am aware.

Comment: What would be the best way to save data then?

Comment: I'm not certain whether you're asking how to do this with or without using an AIR project; can you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified, yes it is an AIR project.

Comment: You can review the [`FileReference` class documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html); it explains how to do what you want - specifically via the [`save()` method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#save()).

Answer (score 3):

Using Flash Player (browser) you can use [`FileReference/save()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#save%28%29) to save to a location of the user's choosing (similar to a download link). Example:

```
// must be in a response to user event, like a click handler
var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
bytes.writeUTFBytes(myXML);
file.save(bytes, "data.xml");
```

Using AIR (app) you can use the [`File` and `FileStream` classes](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/package-detail.html) to write to the filesystem with or without user interaction. Example:

```
var file:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("data.xml");
var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
fileStream.writeUTFBytes(myXML);
fileStream.close();
```

Or to prompt the user for a file location:

```
var file:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("*.xml");
file.browseForSave("Save XML");
file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, select);
function select(e:Event):void {
    var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
    fileStream.writeUTFBytes(myXML);
    fileStream.close();
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks that makes a lot more sense. Can you point me to any simple(ish) examples of this in use?